# How can I interactively debug a python vim script?

Tags: python, debugging, vim, vim-plugin

I have a vim plugin that I'm writing in python, however I need to debug the python script. How can use pdb (or preferably ipdb) in the vim script itself? When I use pdb vim just hangs with no output, and when I use ipdb it turns vim into garbaged output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `rpdb` to debug remotely. Where the remote is just a different tab in your shell.

Just install `Winpdb` (not windows specific anymore) http://winpdb.org/ It includes `rpdb2` which is a remote version of `pdb` and `winpdb` itself is a nice graphical debugger.

Usage example with Winpdb:

```
import rpdb2
rpdb2.start_embedded_debugger('some password')
```

And from Winpdb:

```
File -> Attach
```